# File parsing issues using C dynamic strings

Tags: c, parsing, memory-management, c-strings

Following is a part of a file that needs to be parsed

```
record(ai, "SRC01-VA-IMG1:getPressure")
{
    field(DESC, "Reads Cell  SR-GC1 Pressure")
    field(SCAN, "1 second")
    field(DTYP, "stream")
    field(INP, "@vacuum-XGS600-gc.proto getPressure(1) SR-GC1")
    field(PINI, "YES")
    field(VAL, "0")
    field(PREC, "3")
    field(LOLO, "")     field(LLSV, "NO_ALARM")
    field(HIGH, "")     field(HSV,  "NO_ALARM")
    field(HIHI, "")     field(HHSV, "NO_ALARM")
}
```

The parsing process will read the record name (In the qoutes) and type (ai, in the line record), and each field type and value (in any line that starts with field. e.g. Type: PINI, Value: "YES"). Note that each line can contain more than one record definition. The example contains some interesting cases like multiple fields on the same line, parenthesis inside qoutes, etc.

Here is my code for that purpose:

```
struct field
{
    char* name;
    char* value;
};

struct record
{
    char* name;
    char* type;
    struct field* fields;
};

struct record* get_records(char* file, int* length)
{
    size_t SIZE = 0;
    size_t fSIZE = 1;
    const int N = 100;
    struct record* records = malloc(1 * sizeof(struct record));
    struct field* fields;
    // char line[N];
    char* line = malloc(N);
    char record_name[100];
    char record_type[10];
    char field_name[10];
    char field_value[100];
    char temp[100];

    int open, close, comma, q1, q2;
    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(line, N, fp))
        {
            line = strtrim(line);
            if(strncmp(line, "record", 6) == 0)
            {
                memset(record_name, 0, sizeof(record_name));
                memset(record_type, 0, sizeof(record_type));

                struct record* r = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
                open = strchr(line, '(') - line + 1;
                close = strchr(line, ')') - line + 1;
                comma = strchr(line, ',') - line + 1;
                q1 = strchr(line, '"') - line + 1;
                q2 = strrchr(line, '"') - line + 1;

                strncpy(record_type, &line[open], comma  - open - 1);
                strncpy(record_name, &line[q1], q2 - q1 - 1);
                record_name[q2 - q1 - 1] = '\0';
                record_type[comma  - open - 1] = '\0';
                r->name = record_name;
                r->type = record_type;

                printf("Name: %s\n", r->name);
                printf("Type: %s\n", r->type);

                fSIZE = 0;
                fields = malloc(100 * sizeof(field)); // HERE
                while(fgets(line, N, fp))
                {
                    struct field* f = malloc(sizeof(struct field));
                    if(strncmp(line, "}", 1) == 0)
                        break;

                    if(strncmp(line, "{", 1) == 0)
                        continue;

                    line = strtrim(line);
                    int i1 = 0;
                    int i2 = 0;
                    char* p1 = strstr(line, "field");
                    char* p2;
                    while(p1 != NULL)
                    {
                        i1 = p1 - line;
                        p2 = strstr(p1 + 1, "field");
                        if(p2 != NULL)
                        {
                            i2 = p2 - line;
                            p1 = strstr(p1 + 1, "field");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i2 = strlen(line);
                            p1 = NULL;
                        }

                        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
                        memset(field_name,  0, sizeof(field_name));
                        memset(field_value, 0, sizeof(field_value));

                        strncpy(temp, &line[i1], i2 - i1); temp[i2-i1] = '\0';
                        printf("Line2 : %s\n", temp);

                        open = strchr(temp, '(') - temp + 1;
                        close = strrchr(temp, ')') - temp + 1;
                        comma = strchr(temp, ',') - temp + 1;
                        q1 = strchr(temp, '\"') - temp + 1;
                        q2 = strrchr(temp, '\"') - temp + 1;

                        strncpy(field_value, &temp[q1], q2 - q1 - 1);         field_value[q2-q1-1] = '\0';
                        strncpy(field_name,  &temp[open], comma  - open - 1); field_name[comma-open-1] = '\0';

                        printf("Name : %s\n", field_name);
                        printf("Value: %s\n\n", field_value);

                        f->name = field_name;
                        f->value = field_value;

                        fields[fSIZE++] = *f;
                    }
                    free(line);
                    line = malloc(N);
                }
                r->fields = fields;
                records[SIZE++] = *r;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Unable to open file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    *length = SIZE;
    // fclose(fp);
    return records;
}

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    struct record* records = get_records("./test.db", &length);

    // printf("Anything \n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        struct record* r = (struct record*) &records[i];
        printf("Name: %s\n", r->name);
        printf("Type: %s\n", r->type);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have two issues with this implementation which I could not figure out:

1. In the `main` function there is a `printf` statement, if uncommented the `printf` inside the loop will print garbage, otherwise correct output.
2. Having `fclose` in the function `get_records` uncommented gives a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. With trial and error I figured out I either use it or use the `malloc` line designated by the comment `HERE`, for some reason using one of them or non the fault goes away. I understand I have something wrong with memory allocation somewhere, I used `valgrind` but it did not help me locating anything

Notes:

1. Constant numbers used in `malloc` are for testing purposes. We have files that contains 100's of records. This leads to a future question, which is better use large enough `malloc` buffer or use `realloc`?
2. Any other implementation in `C`, if any, is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like memory was massively messed up by this implementation due to many calls for `malloc` and `free`. What I did was to replace `char*` in the structs with arrays and `line` definition converted to `char[]` and dereference it in `strtrim` call.